# How can I store my JSON array elements in variables?

Tags: android

Here is my json array having sub array in it. Now i want to store the data of this sub array in an arranged manner in android. Like first record the other,etc..How can i do this?

```
{
    "result": [
        ["", "", "2016-04-22", "", "", "problems since last 5 days", "replace piping", "0", null],
        ["Elec4820", "", "2016-04-25", "", "", "jsjshdjdjjcncnc", "hdjdhdhfbbff", "0", null],
        ["Elec7558", "", "2016-04-25", "", "", "jsjshdjdjjcncnc", "hdjdhdhfbbff", "0", null],
        ["Gara8118", "11827", "2016-03-13", "Completed", "nknm", "too much garbage near front gate causing an unbearable stink.", "garbage ", "0", null],
        ["Nois6091", "17061", "2016-03-11", "Assigned", "Committee Member has been assigned to solve this problem", "too much noise caused by construction carried out by....ccd . .dvdv efv \r\nvvevv ", "cdhvdhb bbcsjc cincs nenvnjk \r\nvndjkn n cnicjisk m \r\niejnivn vvnveivnievnj invjievivn \r\nvienvncn", "1", null],
        ["Wate6487", "14371", "2016-03-14", "In-Progress", "gyghbn", "fegrtb fbvrv ", "ss", "1", null]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Where is your json array? basicly what you need to do is create a model class for the content and then using Gson library parse it into ListArray<YourModel>

Answer (score 0):

Your model class must be something like that:

```
public class Example {

@SerializedName("result")
@Expose
private List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

/**
* 
* @return
* The result
*/
public List<List<String>> getResult() {
return result;
}

/**
* 
* @param result
* The result
*/
public void setResult(List<List<String>> result) {
this.result = result;
}

}
```

After, read the documentation of gson to do this: https://github.com/google/gson

Answer (score 0):

while parsing the json loop through the sub array and add to hashset which is declare inside model